# How to set the named index of associative array dynamically?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to create an array with the following data as example. I want to set the named index dynamically based on the user selected value. But when I set the index to a variable, the declared variable name is considered a string in the array and set as the array index name.

```
var country = userInputFromUi;
var cities = [a,b,c,d];

array.push({
country:cities
})
```

Expected result 
userInputFromUi:[a,b,c,d]

actual result 
country:[a,b,c,d]

Not sure if I am understanding something wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use computed property names like so:

```
array.push({ [country]: cities });
```

Comment: worked like a charm. Thanks

Comment: No worries @user6591323